# C# Access database query

Tags: c#

I created database in ms access and it has GPA column.
In listbox2 i need to list students which GPA is bigger than 2.
how caN I do that?

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE GPA > 2";
while (reader.Read())
{
  listBox2.Items.Add............?
}
```

Help if you can.

Comment: What is wrong with the code that you have? Other than you never execute the command to get the reader....

Comment: What keeps you from searching SO or Google to find one of the replies to simliar *How do I display data from Access/Excel/SQL in a list view/list box/console/whatever* questions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that's just pseudo code you've posted. But if not, you are reading a `DataReader` which is either not initialized or is not using the correct `Command`-sql since you are setting the `CommandText` one line before.

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE GPA > 2";
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // assuming that there's a column with name: StudentName
        listBox2.Items.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("StudentName")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string ConnectionString = "PUT YOU CONNECTION STRING HERE";

con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
con.Open();
string CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE GPA > 2";
cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText);
cmd.Connection = con;
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
lbx.Items.Clear();
while (rdr.Read())
{    
     lbx.Items.Add......
}
```

Comment: put this in a try catch and close the connection in finally block